# rank while looping through an array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var testArray = [{
  value: john,
  count: 5
},
{
  value: henry,
  count: 2
},
{
  value: bill,
  count: 10
}]

testArray.map(function(value) {
  //otherfunctions
})
```

So i have a function where i am already mapping through an array of objects similar to the above. I want to add a third value to the objects of rank based upon the count.
My current thought is to finish my map that i am already doing and then re sort the data based upon the count and then assign a rank based upon the the sorted position in the array. But this seems to be long winded given i am already mapping the array?

Comment: is the original array kind of sorted? - the above is not ...

Comment: Why does this seem long winded to you? I would add add the value to the array with the `map()` function and the resort it with the `sort()`, where pass a function comparing the count number.

Comment: the original is not sorted at all. It seems long winded because i am already mapping the array. So to run two maps seems long winded if that makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vanilla JS:

```
var testArray = [{
  value: john,
  count: 5
},
{
  value: henry,
  count: 2
},
{
  value: bill,
  count: 10
}]

let newArray = testArray.map(function(item) {
  return {
     value: item.value,
     count: item.count,
     newProperty: 'x'
   } 
}).sort(function(x, z) {
  return x.count - z.count;
});
```

ES6:

```
let newArray = testArray
.map(item => {
  return {
     ...item,
     newProperty: 'x'
   } 
}).sort((x, z) => x.count - z.count);
```

P.S. this is the functional way of doing this computation, should have a o(n*nlog n) time, you could do it in a o(n) with an imperative approach, but this is easier to read/understand in my opinion.

**EDIT 1**
After comment from author: wants to add the current count to the items (cannot think of a case where this would be necessary) but just to indulge:

```
let newArray = testArray
.map((item, index) => {
  return {
     ...item,
     currentCount: index
   } 
}).sort((x, z) => x.count - z.count);
```

Read more about [map](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp)

Comment: Thank you, this is 99% of what i want to do and compleatly makes sense. However what i want to do is have what you has as newProperty: 'x', i want that to have a relationship to the count value of each object. so that in this instance the x values would be 2,3,1 (in order of the count). Does that make  sense?

Comment: Just to get this straight, you want each object to hold to be: {value: bill, count: 10, newProperty: [2,3,1]} or you just want to get the [2,3,1] value after the iteration?

Comment: no i want each object to be {value: bill, count: 10, newProperty: 1} where new property is related to the count. So that bill will have a newProperty of 1, john will have a newProperty of 2 and henry of 3.

Comment: thank you that answers it. By the way why do you think its such an unsual thing to do?